# Any hint for evaluating $\int_0^\theta \sec^2(\phi)\cdot\sqrt{\sec2\phi}\,d\phi\;$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

How can I evaluate this integral? $$\int_0^\theta \sec^2(\phi)\cdot\sqrt{\sec2\phi}\,d\phi$$

I tried integral by parts using $u = \sqrt{\sec2\phi}$ and $dv =\sec^2(\phi) d\phi$ but ended up falling into a worse integral to solve

If anyone is curious about the origin of the problem, this integral appears when I tried to calculate the length of a hyperbola projected onto a sphere via stereographic projection.

In Wolfram alpha I can get the result but I'm curious how to do it, anyway below is the wolfram result, where $E(\phi,2)$ is the Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind with $k=2$ and $F(\phi,2)$ Elliptic Integral of the First Kind with $k=2$

$$\sqrt{\sec(2\phi)} \left(\sqrt{\cos(2\phi)} E(\phi,2) + \sqrt{\cos(\phi)} F(\phi,2) - \sin(2\phi) + \tan(\phi) \right)$$

Comment: If Wolfram Alpha gives an "Elliptic Integral" then it has no elementary antiderivative. So don't waste the time to go find one as it does not exist.

Comment: Yes I know but I'm not trying to find an elementary answer, I'm more interested in the process to get to the answer.

Comment: Let the software handles it for you. If it returns an elementary solution, then you know you can do it yourself using the method you know. If not, then you know you will get stuck at some point when trying to use the methods you learned at school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $$\tan \phi = t, \qquad \sec^2 \!\phi \,d\phi = dt$$
transforms the definite integral to
$$\int_0^{\tan \theta} \sqrt{\frac{1 + t^2}{1 - t^2}} \,dt = E(t \mid -1)\big\vert_0^{\tan \theta} = E(\tan \theta \mid -1) ,$$
where $E$ is the [incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) (N.b. notation conventions for elliptic integrals vary.) The first equality follows from recognizing the integral as the Legendre normal form of $E$ for $k^2 = -1$.

Notice that for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ the (then improper) integral is equal to $E(i) = \sqrt{2} E\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, where here $E(\,\cdot\,)$ denotes the *complete* elliptical integral of the second kind.

Comment: I think that the argument is not correct. Should it be $E\left(\left.\sin ^{-1}(\tan (\theta ))\right|-1\right)$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The issue may just be a matter of conflicting notation (which is regrettably common in the context of elliptic integrals); see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Argument_notation .

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I shall prcise that I use Mathematica notations. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the same steps as @Travis Willse (but using Mathematica notations)
$$f(\theta)= \int_0^\theta \sec^2(\phi)\,\sqrt{\sec2\phi}\,d\phi=E\left(\left.\sin ^{-1}(\tan (\theta ))\right|-1\right)$$

If you need it for calculations, you can have quite accurate results using its $[2n+1,2n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ built around $\theta=0$.

Using for example

$$P_3=\theta\,\, \frac{1-\frac{63456821089 }{29809409916}\theta ^2+\frac{84897035101 }{74523524790}\theta^4-\frac{3354760809383 }{37559856494160}\theta ^6 } {1-\frac{27776587011 }{9936469972}\theta ^2+\frac{36309994555 }{14904704958}\theta
   ^4-\frac{3572751912491 }{5365693784880} \theta ^6}+O\left(\theta
   ^{15}\right)$$

$$\Phi=\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \Big[E\left(\left.\sin ^{-1}(\tan (\theta ))\right|-1\right)-P_3 \Big]^2\,d\theta=1.129\times 10^{-4}$$ Using $P_4$ insteads leads to $\Phi=  2.353\times 10^{-5}$